# Stuck At D3+Angular directive code

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I am new to Directive and to D3,  I am trying to wrap this D3 script into a custom directive, this d3 script loads data from csv file and creates a table on html:

It works fine when it's not in Angular but the problem that it doesn't load the ng-bind (and ( also attempted to use {{}} expressions work, didn't work either) :

```
d3.text("data.csv", function (data) {
                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("#chart")
                    .append("table")
                    .attr("class", "chartable")
                    .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")
                    .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function (d) { return d; }).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function (d) { return d; })

                d3.select(".chartable")
                .selectAll("tr")
                .append("td")
                .attr("ng-bind", "addedDays")


                d3.select("#chart").append("br")
                d3.select("#chart").append("br")

            });
```

In directive wrapped version (not working):

```
app.directive("dataTable", function ($parse) {
var directiveDefinitionObject1 = {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
   // scope: { data: '=tableData' },
    link: function () {

        d3.text("data.csv", function (data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

            var container = d3.select("#chart")
                .append("table")
                .attr("class", "chartable")
                .selectAll("tr")
                .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                .append("tr")
                .selectAll("td")
                .data(function (d) { return d; }).enter()
                .append("td")
                .text(function (d) { return d; })

            d3.select(".chartable")
            .selectAll("tr")
            .append("td")
            .attr("ng-bind", "addedDays")


            d3.select("#chart").append("br")
            d3.select("#chart").append("br")

        });

    }
};

return directiveDefinitionObject1;
```

});

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <data-table>
        <div id="chart" >
</div>

    </data-table>
</div>
```

The reason I am doing this is because I want to use ng-bind (or angular expressions) in D3.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AngularJS directives such as `ng-bind` and `{{ }}` need to be compiled and linked to a scope using the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Comment: If you just want to evaluate an Angular Expression, use [scope.$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval).